# How to calculate difference of between two bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi i have two bootstrap datepickers and i want to calculate the difference between the dates and show the number of days in a input box. Code:-

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="fdate" name="fdate">
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="tdate" name="tdate">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="days" id="days">
```

JavaScript:-

```
<script>
$(function() {

$('#fdate').datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yy",
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        $("#tdate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0');
    }
}); 

$('#tdate').datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yy",
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+1Y+6M');
        var start = $("#fdate").datepicker("getDate");
        var end = $("#tdate").datepicker("getDate");
        var days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        $("#days").val(days);
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

I have tried the above javascript to do it but it doesn't work. I am not sure whether it is the right way or not. Please help me in pointing out what is going wrong or if there is a better way of doing it. ANy help is highly appreciated.

Comment: add some jsfiddle for better and quick responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the onchange event of date picker. Chnage code according to the beloe]w code to get the date different like this

```
$(function() {

$('#fdate').datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yy",
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $('#tdate').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#fdate").val());
});
$('#tdate').datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yy",
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        var start = $("#fdate").val();
        var startD = new Date(start);
        var end = $("#tdate").val();
        var endD = new Date(end);
        var diff = parseInt((endD.getTime()-startD.getTime())/(24*3600*1000));
        $("#days").val(diff);
});

});
```

Working Example : https://plnkr.co/edit/D7gZnJBa3q6MiyCriT1U?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the solution it worked. I have another query is it possible to start the date in the second datepicker from the next date of the first datepicker.

Comment: yes  it is , i have updated the plunker for the same

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input name="startdate" readonly="" placeholder="Start date" id="startDatepicker" type="text">
<input name="enddate" readonly="" placeholder="End date" id="endDatepicker" type="text">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#startDatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#endDatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#endDatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startDatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
```